# how to eliminate the first 2 entries from a path in php

Tags: php, path, explode

i have a variable that shows me the path to a directory like below:

```
$dir = uploads/sha256/folder1/subfolder1/subsubfolder1
```

How can i "cut off" the first 2 directories from `$dir` so that it becomes:

```
$dir = folder1/subfolder1/subsubfolder1
```

sample code:

```
$dir = "uploads/sha256/folder1/subfolder1/subsubfolder1";
$pieces = explode("/", $dir);

echo $pieces[2]; // piece2
```

This gives me only `folder1`

And i need the complete path after the sha256
so what i actually try to achieve is something like this:

```
echo $pieces[>2];
```

Comment: Have you tried _anything_ to accomplish this?  There are a whole bunch of string-related functions that are well-documented.  Surely you could have come up with something to try.

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: i tried to use the `explode` but it gives me only 1 piece of the path. After the `sha256` the directories are variable. so i want to cut off the first 2 directories only

Comment: Then you used it wrong. Show your code.

Comment: code above updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture `()` everything after the first two directories and replace with that:

```
$dir = preg_replace('#[^/]+/[^/]+/(.*)#', '$1', $dir);
```

Or you can explode it, slice all elements after the first two and implode it again:

```
$dir = implode('/', array_slice(explode('/', $dir), 2));
```